# How to make browser window come from background to foreground with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm making a browser-based alarm clock, and users should be able to preset one of the following to occur when the timer reaches 0:

- Have a sound play
- Have the minimized or in-the-background window with the alarm clock on it come to the foreground

The second one is the problem. I figure I can make a "_blank" link be activated when 0 is reached, but popups suck, and the user'd have to close it as well. What would be really nice is if the window with the alarm clock could be come the active one. How could that be done?

Also I know that people don't like to have windows appear and interrupt their work, which is why it's left as an optional thing.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, there is no reliable way of doing this (I mean the background window coming to foreground).

Comment: If this were possible, don't you think obnoxious ads all over the web would be doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You have no control over this behavior. You can not do it, and I would insist that you do not even try.